# Finitely generated Tensor Product

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Does $M \otimes N $ finitely generated imply that $M$ and $N$ are also finitely generated? I know that the converse is true, but I'm not really sure about this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No : there are examples where neither is finitely generated, and examples where one of them is and not the other: take for instance $\mathbb{Q}\otimes\text{(any torsion abelian group)}$, which is $0$.

Now it's known that there are finitely generated and infinitely generated torsion abelian groups, so that's it.

Comment: Oh yeah , Thanks.

Comment: Can u give me an example of a infinitely generated torsion abelian group? Does $\mathbb{Z}_{2}^\mathbb{N} work ?$

Comment: nevermind i understand it now